# how to select only first 10 characters from sql column with Hibernate Criteria

Tags: hibernate

I have a column in mysql  "description "
which value is like   "this is a description of some of the products we have the list of the products is big enough.."

now i want to retrieve it from mysql in to java but only first 10 characters with hibernate criteria

from below i can get this above value from mysql ,but i just want to get only first 10 like ""this is a description of some of the products" not more than this

any way of doing it in hibernate .

```
    Patients patients = null;
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Patients.class);

    List rsList = crit.list();
    for(Iterator it=rsList.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
    {
        patients = (Patients)it.next();
```

thanks

Comment: Take a look at @Formula and then figure out how to get the database to only return the first 10 rows of the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to create a NamedQuery and create a select statement with something like this : `select left(<mycolumn>,10) as <myColumn10> from <mytable>`

then you call this NamedQuery from your code.
Here is an example on how to use a NamedQuery: [NameQuery Example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-named-query-examples/)

Comment: thanks , you are using select statement , isnt it possible to do it with hibernate criteria .

Comment: I am not a big fan of CreateCriteria :P, bu I found that It might possible by adding Expressions to the criteria. I think this article will help you get started: [link](http://knol.google.com/k/nhibernate-chapter-13-criteria-queries)